# How to vectorize a loop when the whole dataframe is needed in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, vectorization

I have the following problem: I have a Pandas Dataframe which looks like this:
`pd.DataFrame(columns=['eqpid','entering_time','leaving_time'])` Eqpid are strings, while entering_time and leaving_time are timestamps. It contains over 48 Million rows, but the first few look like this:

```
         eqpid   entering_time         leaving_time  
4        1       2017-01-01 00:00:10   2017-01-01 00:04:05
7        1       2017-01-01 00:00:20   2017-01-01 00:04:05
10       1       2017-01-01 00:00:33   2017-01-01 00:04:05
15       1       2017-01-01 00:00:46   2017-01-01 00:04:05
22       1       2017-01-01 00:01:00   2017-01-01 00:04:05
24       1       2017-01-01 00:01:11   2017-01-01 00:04:05
27       1       2017-01-01 00:01:24   2017-01-01 00:04:05
```

Now, I want to know for every row, how many other rows fulfill all of the conditions:

1. eqpid = row['eqpid']  -> same eqpid
2. entering_time < row['entering_time']  -> all rows where entering time is smaller
3. leaving_time > row['entering_time']  -> all rows where leaving time is bigger than entering time of the row

So, in the end, the DataFrame should look like this:

```
         eqpid   entering_time         leaving_time         result  
4        1       2017-01-01 00:00:10   2017-01-01 00:04:05  0
7        1       2017-01-01 00:00:20   2017-01-01 00:04:05  1
10       1       2017-01-01 00:00:33   2017-01-01 00:04:05  2
15       1       2017-01-01 00:00:46   2017-01-01 00:04:05  3
22       1       2017-01-01 00:01:00   2017-01-01 00:04:05  4
24       1       2017-01-01 00:01:11   2017-01-01 00:04:05  5
27       1       2017-01-01 00:01:24   2017-01-01 00:04:05  6
```

I tried to do it in three ways:
First, a simple iteration, but it took way too long to execute (several weeks):

```
array_result = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    sub_df = df.loc[(df['entering_time'] < row['entering_time']) & (df['leaving_time'] > row['entering_time']
    array_result.append(len(sub_df))
df['result'] = array_result
```

Second, I tried to work with `pd.apply()`in the following way:

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: len(df[(df['eqpid'] == row['eqpid']) & (df['entering_time'] < row['entering_time']) & (df['leaving_time'] > row['entering_time'])]), axis=1)
```

This works fine if I only take 40,000 rows, but kills my memory for the whole DataFrame. I considered to loop through the DataFrame, but in this context the iteratable sub_df`s would sometimes contain over 1 Million rows, so this did not help either and also seems to be a 'dirty solution'.

Third, I tried to vectorize the problem in the following way:

```
def result(data,r_entertime,r_eqpid):
    data['result'] = len(data.loc[(data['eqpid'] == r_eqpid) 
                         & (data['entering_time'] < r_entertime) 
                         & (data['leaving_time'] > r_entertime)])
    return data['result']

df['result'] = result(df,df['entering_time'],df['eqpid'])
```

This is extremely fast, but unfortunately, all entrys for the new column result are 0. So, my question is, is it possible to use vectorization in this context? All examples for vectorization I found so far only used informations of only **one** row, while I have to use a lookup in the whole column in each row.

Can someone help me here?

Comment: please provide some sample input data and expected output

Comment: How do you load the dataframe? Do you process the CSV in chunks?

Comment: Data is now described, thank you for the remark. @Andrea I load the DataFrame with feather.import. This works fast and reliable

Comment: why do you pass `df['entering_time']` as `r_entertime` to `result`? like that you have `data['entering_time'] < df['entering_time']`, which will never be true...

Comment: @mcsoini i tried to pass the row's entering time within this argument, but my lack of understanding for vectorization becomes obvious here. I leaned on this description: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-make-your-pandas-loop-71-803-times-faster-805030df4f06